# facebook dynamic meta tags with php

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i have problems with generating dynamic facebook meta tags after a submit form. I have a share button and it should get the parameters i provide in the link, here is the code:

Head:

```
if(isset($_POST['confirm']))
{
$lock=$_POST['lock'];
$love_letter=$_POST['love'];
}
echo'
<meta property="og:url" content="http://websoftit.ro/lackoflove/registration.php?type=1&love='.$love_letter.'&lock_type='.$lock.'"> 
<meta property="og:title" content="Lock of Love">
<meta property="og:description" content="You have created your own virtual love lock! Why not share with your friends on facebook?
        Your love lock link is: '.$lock.'">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://websoftit.ro/lackoflove/images/lovelock/biglock'.$lock.'.png">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="200">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="200">
';
```

Now the code after submit

```
if(isset($_POST['confirm']))
{
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$country=$_POST['country'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$type=$_POST['type'];
$lock=$_POST['lock'];
$love_letter=$_POST['love'];
$cookie=$_COOKIE['cookie'];

<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://websoftit.ro/lackoflove/registration.php?type=1&love='.$love_letter.'&lock_type='.$lock.'" data-type="button_count"></div>

}
```

And the problem is that when i press on the share button it doesnt get the parameters for love_letter and lock_type from description and image, it worked few months ago having php variables in link but seems they changed something

Comment: Wheres the echo? You've pasted html inside php tags.

Comment: i just pased some fragments of code, didnt copy pasted echo too, but there is an echo :)